# Meaning of CR-Automorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

What is the meaning of the CR-Automorphism and CR-Manifold? I tried to find the definition from the web. Is it Continuous Real ....?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, CR stands for Cauchy-Riemann. These are $(2n-1)$-dimensional manifolds that, like hypersurfaces in $\mathbb C^n$, have an integrable system of $(n-1)$-dimensional complex subspaces in each tangent space. A CR-automorphism is a diffeomorphism preserving the CR structure.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're satisfied with the answer, feel free to accept it so that the question goes off the unanswered list.